# Can i provide link for file stored in shared path (UNC Path)

Tags: javascript, html, .net, web

I have a web application where the page lists the files which are stored in UNC path something like this below

```
FileName   Path
--------   -----
profile1  \\devserver1\share\profile1.doc
profile2  \\devserver1\share\profile2.doc
```

Can i provide the hyperlink for the second column and when user clicks the link the file should open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the webapplication is hosted by a server on the intranet and the users have access to the devserver1, then you can create a hyperlink:

```
<a href="file:///\\devserver1\share\profile1.doc">\\devserver1\share\profile1.doc</a>
```

If your users cannot access devserver1, then you have to add "proxy site" that loads the content of the requested file on the server and streams it back to the user.